# Android: Start to collect from Flow when button pressed?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to build a sign up and login screen with Firebase Authentication.

When a user enters an email and password, they can click a sign up or login button which subsequently makes a network request to Firebase to perform the respective action.

Now, the network request returns a `Flow` which looks like this for the login action and similarly for the sign up action:

```
fun authenticate(email: String, password: String): Flow<NetworkResponse<Boolean>> = flow {
    emit(NetworkResponse.Loading)
    try {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
        emit(NetworkResponse.Success(true))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(NetworkResponse.Error(e))
    }
}
```

The button in the UI displays some text like `Sign up` or `Login`. The intended design is when the user clicks on the button, a loading animation appears when the `Flow` emits `NetworkResponse.Loading`, then either performs some action on `NetworkResponse.Success` or displays an error message on `NetworkResponse.Error`.

Normally, I would collect UI state from the ViewModel like this from the screen:

```
@Composable
LoginScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    // ...
}
```

If I do this with the `authenticate` flow, then the screen will display the `NetworkResponse.Loading` loading animation instead of the intended text. So, I need to find a way to only start collecting from the flow when the user clicks the sign up or login button.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you add an IDLE state to your UiState? That'd then be the initial state which you can collect as state like you said. All in all it appears you're trying to mix "lower/domain" flows straight to the UI without transforming or mapping them.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini So, if I add an Idle state to the screen's UI state, how should I change this when the user clicks sign up or login? Would this mean collecting the authenticate Flow from within the viewModel?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini No, I should've made it clearer but I am transforming the flows. The screen's UI state is a sealed interface with Loading, Success, Error states.

Comment: You observe your VM flow from your UI. When the user taps the action, you forward this to the VM. The VM starts a coroutine in its scope, emits the loading state, then calls and collects the response from the `authenticate` function, performs all it's needed, and emits a UIState that the UI is observing indicating the result(s) of the authenticate. Does that make sense?

Comment: `Would this mean collecting the authenticate Flow from within the viewModel?`. Yes.

Comment: Why would you return a Flow when you authenticate a user? In my opinion, the `authenticate` function should be a simple suspend function. I cannot see any reason why you would return a flow.

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help, it's a working solution. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword). See, no need to use a Flow in case of authenticating the users.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yeh, I think you're right. If I change the state of the UI state to Loading before I start to collect from the flow then there's probably no point to emit Loading from the authenticate flow.

Comment: Yes, you can set up Loading directly into the ViewModel. Besides that, the loading state it's a state that is related to the UI and doesn't need to be set in the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm suggesting in the comments is simple:

1. UI -> Observes ViewModel.uiState (Sealed class Success/Loading/ETc.)
2. ViewModel exposes an action like `onAuthenticate(...)`.
3. UI is "tapped" and you call `viewModel.onAuthenticate(...)`.
4. View Model does `viewModelScope.launch { ... }` and calls `uiState.Loading()`, then `authenticate(...)`, deals with that, and emits `uiState.Success(...)` (or error).
5. UI was observing this, so will react accordingly.

There are multiple ways to approach step 4.

You can have a series of internal flows that you ultimately `combine(...)`, or just locally handle that with `.map` and such, or even delegate most to a suspend function in an injected `use-case` or similar class:

PSEUDO CODE:

```
class AuthenticateUseCase(yourAuthRepo: AuthRepo) {
   suspend operator fun invoke((user, pass) : YourResponse {
       return yourAuthRepo.authenticate(user, pass) // or even handle errors with a `when` or similar case to decide what YourResponse means. It's usually some form of `Responses<T>` that you create.
        // this "empty" passing-hands-proxy use-case doesn't really do anything here, but it's the starting point to abstract the operation.
   }
}
```

You inject the above in your VM, and so you can have (in the VM) something like:

```
fun onAuthenticate(user, pass) {
   viewModelScope.launch {
       uistate.emit(loading)
       val result = authUseCase(user, pass)
       uistate.emit(Success(result)) // obviously deal with errors, this is pseudo-code.
   }
}
```

Your UI is happy.

Comment: Yeh, that’s what I thought you meant. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Absolutely! Feel free to post another question if you get stuck. That's how I'd likely do it, i'm sure other people have other ideas as well.  The above works fine (and is quite testable). Good luck!